# Pass around php class object using Ajax and jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I would like to pass around a php class instance between PHP and JavaScript by using Ajax and jQuery.

I need to access data properties in JavaScript and execute methods in PHP. The following piece of code shows what I mean:

index.php

```
<?php require_once("php/foo.php") ?>
var bar = <?php echo json_encode(new foo()); ?>;

// do something with 'bar'
$.post("ajax/foo.ajax.php", { foo : bar }, function(data) {});
```

foo.ajax.php

```
require_once("php/foo.php);

if (isset($_POST["foo"]))
{
   $bar = $_POST["foo"];
   // do something with 'bar'
   echo json_encode($bar);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a mechanism in PHP to accomplish that right now.  You can use serialize and unserialize to retain object structure, and json_encode will pull all of the public properties out of your object, but json_decode will return it into a state of a StdObject (standard object) in PHP.

A workaround for this would be the iterate over the properties returned and reset them in your object.